# Rails, param is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, parameters

When i trying save , i get error.

> param is missing or the value is empty: help

where my mistake? I see this error the first time

my **application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authenticate_admin_user!
    authenticate_user!
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def help_request
    @help = Help.new(help_params)
    if @help.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      #
    end
  end

  private

  def help_params
    params.require(:help).permit(:name, :email, :messages)
  end
end
```

and my partial **_help_request.html.slim**

```
div id="help_request"
  h1 Help form
  hr
  = form_for Help.new, as: :post, url: help_request_path do |f|

    = f.label :name
    br
    br
    = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control',
                          placeholder: 'your name'

    = f.label :email
    br
    br 
    = f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control',
                           placeholder: 'your email'

    = f.label :messages
    br
    br 
    = f.text_area :messages, class: 'form-control',
                             placeholder: 'your message'
    br
    br
    = f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of `as: :post` in your form declaration. It seems that `params[:post]` is present, but not `params[:help]`.